# How to join to the domain, without changing the DNS settings

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dns, samba, amazon-ec2

I have my Samba4 setup in the EC2 & I can join the windows clients fine, if I assign my instance public IP as the DNS server. But my requirement is, irrespective of any DNS IP assigned to the client machine, it should be able to join to the domain. Please guide me, what changes I should make at the client, instead of changing the DNS address.

Answer (score 1):

### It can't be done.

Computers in an Active Directory domain use DNS to locate services within the domain. Therefore to join or otherwise participate in the domain, the computers must use a DNS server that will correctly resolve the domain-related queries. Normally this is an Active Directory DNS server. It is possible to use a non AD-based DNS server, but that requires the administrator to populate (and worse, continually update) the other server with the many records involved in the AD infrastructure.

Bottom line: If you use AD, you must use AD DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can.

I found the way. All you have to do is, make the SRV records for each protocol & point it to your server. That's it. Attaching the screenshot for reference.

[image]